# intern test not using configured registry requestProvider in dojo

Tags: dojo, intern

I'm following [this article](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2014/07/14/mocking-data-with-intern/) to mock response in dojo.

My mocker is very similar to the one in the article except this:

```
registry.register(/\/testIntern/, function (url, options) {
  return when({
                value: "Hello World"
            });
```

In my understanding, this should map to any request that contains "/testIntern" on the address.

My testcase is quite simple:

```
// similar to example
var testRest= new Rest("/testIntern", true);
            testRest("").then(lang.hitch(this, function (data) {
                assert.deepEqual("Hello World", data.value, "Expected 'Hello World', but got" + data.value);
            }));
```

It really should be quite simple. But when I run this test, I got 404 Not Found. It looks like the REST call in the test doesn't try to use the mocking service. Why?

Comment: What module is your registry.register call in?  Are you specifying `dojoConfig.requestProvider` correctly so that your handlers are registered?  Are you using dojo/store or dstore?

Comment: @KenFranqueiro, the example in that link doesn't mention anything about registry.register call in. What does this do?  dojoConfig.requestProvider is set to "dojo/request/registry". Why do I want to use store for this simple test?

Comment: The very first example in that article includes a `registry.register` call.  I asked which store implementation you're using because you're evidently instantiating `Rest` which I was assuming is either `dstore/Rest` or `dojo/store/JsonRest`.

Comment: @KenFranqueiro, I'm using dojo/store/JsonRest. I can't find how the example implement any store. In the first example, the registry.register call doesn't seem to be about a specific store? Sorry I'm reasonably new to dojo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are generally correct in your thought that registering a URL with `dojo/request/registry` should pass anything referencing that URL via `dojo/request` through your handler.

Unfortunately, `dojo/store/JsonRest` uses the `dojo/_base/xhr` module which uses `dojo/request/xhr` directly, not `dojo/request`.  Any registrations created with `dojo/request/registry` (and any setting of `defaultProvider`) will unfortunately be lost on JsonRest.

You might want to have a look at [dstore](http://dstorejs.io/) - its Rest store implements the same server requests as `dojo/store/JsonRest` but it uses `dojo/request` instead of being hard-coded to a specific provider.  (`dojo/request` defaults to `dojo/request/xhr` in browsers anyway, but can be overridden via `dojoConfig.requestProvider`.)  dstore contains adapters for translating between dstore's API and the dojo/store API, if you need to use it with widgets that operate with the latter.